# Find the limit of $(1+a_n)^{c_n}e^{-a_nc_n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $a_n$ and $c_n$ be sequences of real numbers such that $a_n$ converges to $0$, and $c_na_n^2$ converges to $0$. Determine $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+a_n)^{c_n}e^{-a_nc_n}$.

Answer (score 5):

One may use a Taylor series expansion, as $n \to \infty$, 
$$
\begin{align}
(1+a_n)^{c_n}e^{-a_nc_n}&=e^{c_n\log(1+a_n)}e^{-a_nc_n}
\\&=e^{c_n(a_n+O(a^2_n))}e^{-a_nc_n}
\\&=e^{c_na_n+O(c_na^2_n))}e^{-a_nc_n}
\\&=e^{O(c_na^2_n)}
\\&\to 1
\end{align}
$$ since $a_n \to 0$ and $c_na_n^2 \to 0$.

Comment: Simple, quick, and elegant.